# Symfony UTF-8 Characters not correct displayed

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, doctrine, twig

I have a problem with I already spend several hours: Symfony doesn't display UTF-8 string correctly.

**DB**

My DB has UTF-8 (ssh using UFT-8 tool):

```
db2 "select name from client";

NAME
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DefaultÄÜÖäüö
```

**Simple GUI:**

Using some dump I get this:

```
dump(mb_detect_encoding($entities[0]->getName()));
```

"UTF-8"

```
dump($entities[0]->getName());
```

b"DefaultÄÜÖäüö"

***the b is strange...***

**in Twig:**

Default����

When I use

```
ISO: {{ entity.name| convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')
```

DefaultÄÜÖäüö

Metatag is set

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

I have tried to change it in AppKernel.php (really does not matter if code is set or comment out)

```
   public function getCharset()
    {
        return 'UTF-8';
    }
```

Also in config.yml for the database  (really does not matter if code is set or comment out):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        charset:  UTF8
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Are all your files saved as `UTF-8` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.3"` on your composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to your `my.cnf` or `server.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
# Version 5.5.3 introduced "utf8mb4", which is recommended
collation-server     = utf8mb4_general_ci # Replaces utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4            # Replaces utf8
```

I'm presuming you are using MySQL.

You can also set in your `config.yml` file. See the ["Setting up the database to be UTF8"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to store string as encoded unicode and decode it when you access it like so:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @final
 */
trait DescriptionTrait
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return \utf8_decode($this->description);
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $description
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = \utf8_encode($description);
        return $this;
    }
}
```